# How to create an adaptor to a Wearable Recycler View?

Tags: android, wearables, wearable-recyclerview

I want to create an adapter for a `WearableRecyclerView` for my wearable app, I read that it is necessary otherwise you can't create a curved circular menu. All the things I see are for the `RecyclerView` on mobile phones, my question is how do you do the same but for the Wearable `RecylcerView`?

The reason I ask this is because I am trying to create a menu that looks like this:
[image]

```
public class WRecyclerViewAdapter extends WearableRecyclerView.Adapter<MainMenuAdapter.RecyclerViewHolder> {
@NonNull
@Override
public MainMenuAdapter.RecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MainMenuAdapter.RecyclerViewHolder holder, int position) {

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return 0;
}
```

}

this is the class that is suppose to be the adapter and I have no idea what to write